# error app not installed after publish to google play

Tags: android, cordova, build, publish

recently i made an android game and i found the current problem.
when the application is run before publishing to Google Play it's fine, but when the application is published and I try to download it I get the problem "the application is not installed" I can't open my application when I click the icon, but if I open it through the application settings it can run normally.
tell me where the mistake is, I hope you are blessed

sorry if my language is not understood, I use google translate :)

I hope this problem can be solved soon, thank you

Comment: Uninstall the app first, then try again from Google Play

Comment: Same issue here. App runs fine on the emulator, and installing package from APK on the real device. But after install from Google Play, fails with error "App is not installed on your device" when I tap the icon (Obviously app is installed). Reinstalling the app does not help. Any ideas?